# 2D Global Array Error - Array Bound Is Not An Integer Constant

Tags: c++, arrays, global

I can't seem to find an answer to this. I realize that the integer value used in an array must be known at compile time, and what I have here seems to meet that criteria. If I use:

```
int L = 50;                     // number of interior points in x and y

int pts = L + 2;                // interior points + boundary points
double  u[pts][pts],            // potential to be found
    u_new[pts][pts];            // new potential after each step
```

Then I get the array bound error, even though the value for pts is known at compile time. The code is accepted, however, when I use:

```
int L = 50;                     // number of interior points in x and y

int pts = L + 2;                // interior points + boundary points
double  u[52][52],              // potential to be found
    u_new[52][52];              // new potential after each step
```

Am I missing something here? If not, what can I do to have it accept pts?

Answer (score 3):

When you use

```
int L = 50;
int pts = L + 2;
```

`L` and `pts` cannot be used as dimensions of arrays since they are not compile time constants. Use `constexpr` qualifiers to let the compiler know that they can be computed at compile time, and hence can be used as dimensions of arrays.

```
constexpr int L = 50;
constexpr int pts = L + 2;
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have known better. I used const int and that was accepted.

Comment: @LeighK, if you are able to use C++11, prefer `constexpr` over `const`.